# getElementById is returning null after openeing a new html file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm loading a new html file after clicking on an image in other html file via javascript. I do this by saying `window.location.href="page2.html"` Now, when tryign to access an element on page2.html using `getElementById()` it is always returning null. I figure that my DOM is created from the first page so it's returning null because the id I'm providing is not on the first page, but the second page. How can I refresh my DOM to represent my new page?

My first html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<head>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="homepage">
    <header>
        <h1> $ Cheap Gamer $ </h1>
        <p> Welcome to the best website in the world to find great deals on cheap games </p>
    </header>

    <ul>
        <h1 id=pcheader> PC Games </h1>
        <li>Crysis</li>
        <p>An intense first person shooter. $9.99</p>
        <img id="1" src="crysis.jpg" onClick="showDetails(id)">

        <li>Battlefield</li>
        <p>A great multi player experience. $5.99</p>
        <img id="2" src="bc2.jpg"  onClick="showDetails(bc2)">
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <h2 id=mobileheader> Mobile Games </h2>
        <li>Angry Birds</li>
        <p> The most popular mobile game of all time! Availabe now for free!</p>
        <img  id="3" src="angry.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" onClick="showDetails(angry)">

        <li>Angry Pigs</li>
        <p> The long awaited follow up the the classic Angry Birds. Now for free!</p>
        <img   id="4" src="angrybirds.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" onClick="showDetails(angrybirds)">
    </ul>

    <footer id="footer">
        Contact tylerpfaff@gmail.com for any inquries
    </footer>

</body>
```

My second html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>

<h1 id=headertext></h1>
<img id=boxart height="500" width="500"></img>
</html>
```

My script file

```
function showDetails(imgid){
var imgsrc;
    window.location.href="page2.html"
    alert(imgid);
    switch(imgid)
    {
    case "1":
    alert(document.getElementById("boxart"));
    break;
    case 2:
    imgsrc="BattefieldLarge.jpg"
    break;

    case 3:
    imgsrc="AngryBirdsLarge.jpg"
    break;

    case 4:
    imgsrc="AngryPigsLarge.jpg"
    break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you including your script on page2.html as well?

Comment: If you do "document.getElementById('element')" etc. on page1.html is referring to the context of page1.html only. You need to create a link to your script on the other page so that you can target the elements of that page from the same script as well.

Comment: I have this on both of my html pages <script src="myScript.js"></script>

Comment: Can you post sample code? When you reload the page you empty the DOM. but it is easier to find a solution when you post some code.

Comment: Posted. The alert in case "1" says null everytime.

Comment: Yes, but for now I'm just debugging with the first image and id.